# Use of Grep command using regular expression

Tags: linux, grep

```
  Delay: 10x100
  Delay: 10x100
  Delay: 10x100
  Delay: 10x100
  Delay: 10x100
  Delay: 10x100
  Delay: 10x100
  Delay: 10x100
  Delay: 10x100
  Delay: 10x100
  Delay: 10x100
  Delay: 10x100
  Delay: 10x100
  Delay: 10x10
```

Above is the  data of my txt file how can i get records after Delay:  and before x100.please tell me the exact syntax?

Comment: I would use [GNU awk](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/index.html) instead of `grep`

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you. Show us the actual code that you've tried and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -F"[:x]” '$NF==100{ print $2 }' txt.file
```

Comment: Maybe add `$3==100` before the opening brace if that is also a requirement (i.e. don't print the line with x10)?

Answer (score 2):

If you have GNU grep, it actually can be done with `grep`.

```
grep -Po '^Delay: \K[1-9][0-9]*' filename
```

Comment: I am using MAc it doesnt gives me output